# Is there a continuous compact supported function $f: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ such that $f^{-1}$ is continuous differentiable

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is there a  continuous compact supported function $f: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ such that $f^{-1}$ is continuous differentiable?

I don't know which theorem is related to this question, the inverse function theorem? But the Jacobian matrix is not a square matrix and what is its inverse matrix?

Comment: what should be the domain of $f^{-1}$ ?

Comment: the range of $f$ I think.

Comment: OK so just map a disc onto itself, making the other coordinates zero.

Comment: Ok, if we change the position of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ in the title?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: That map is not compact supported.

Comment: @QuangHoang oh just do the usual trick to make it zero outside some compact set.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot. Explicitly, note that stereographic projection is a smooth homeomorphism of $S^n-\text{north pole}$ to $\Bbb R^n$. Given that $S^n$ is embedded in $\Bbb R^{2n}$, you can construct the desired map.

Comment: Well, quite different answer, I am not familiar with homeomorphism, I am stuck now....

Comment: Take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection

Answer (score 0):

No.

If $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are both continuous, then $f$ would be a homeomorphism. It is a standard theorem of topology that $\mathbb{R^n}$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R^m}$ for $n \neq m$. One could show this by demonstrating that they have different (topological) dimension, and that this property is invariant under homeomorphism.

I know this ignores most of the content of your question (compact support, differentiability), but it cuts down to a much deeper, topological truth.